# How matches an element immediately preceded by a sibling element using and nth-child with Xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath, css-selectors

This selector `foo > [baz=3] ~ bar` is equivalent to `//foo/[@baz="3"]/following-sibling::bar` xpath

And this selector `foo > :nth-child(2n+1)` is equivalent to `//foo/[position() mod 2=1]` xpath

Using this structure:

```
<foo>
    <bar baz="1">one</bar>
    <bar baz="2">two</bar>
    <bar baz="3">tree</bar>
    <bar baz="4">four</bar>
    <bar baz="5">five</bar>
    <bar baz="6">six</bar>
    <bar baz="7">seven</bar>
    <bar baz="8">eight</bar>
    <bar baz="9">nine</bar>
    <bar baz="10">ten</bar>
</foo>
```

- with `//foo/[@baz="3"]/following-sibling::bar` matches/returns:

  ```
  <bar baz="4">four</bar>
  <bar baz="5">five</bar>
  <bar baz="6">six</bar>
  <bar baz="7">seven</bar>
  <bar baz="8">eight</bar>
  <bar baz="9">nine</bar>
  <bar baz="10">ten</bar>
  ```
- with `//foo/[position() mod 2=1]` matches/returns:

  ```
  <bar baz="1">one</bar>
  <bar baz="3">tree</bar>
  <bar baz="5">five</bar>
  <bar baz="7">seven</bar>
  <bar baz="9">nine</bar>
  ```

But when combine `following-sibling::` and `position()` the `position()` counting elements by `following-sibling::` and not by all childs elements in  parent (eg.: `<foo>` tag), I would like to do this in Xpath:

```
foo > [bar=3]:nth-child(2n+1)
```

But this `//foo/[@baz="3"]/following-sibling::[position() mod 2=1]` not work (because the position does not count from the first child element)

How can I do this?

> **Note:** I am creating a CSS to Xpath converter.

Comment: Does `last() - position() + 1` help to reverse the indexing?

Comment: @kjhughes thanks, but not work, its returns bar=4, baz=6 and baz=8... the expected is that it returns 5, 7, and 9. Unfortunately the `last()` is also affected by `following-sibling::`